# Leader lines to beginning and ending of polyline using maplex

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, maplex

I have a polyline layer with the labels placed offset with a leader line going to the middle of the polyline. Is there some way to have a leader line go from the end of the line to the label then back to the beginning of the line using maplex? It would be nice to have it automated because I am dealing with a rather large dataset.

Comment: Are you wanting to create something similar to a match line?

Comment: This is not possible with any MapPlex or Standard Label settings and there no built-in way to automate it.  Duplicate overlapping labels is the only way to achieve the effect, but lines vary in length and the two labels will never overlap through automated placement rules if you manage to fix each leader to a different line end.  An Annotation Feature Class, ArcObjects and an expert knowledge of Label manipulation coding would be required to make it at all automated.  Code like that has never been posted on any forum I have seen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think we are going to go with an annotation layer and manually place everything. I've done a lot of reading and couldnt find anything.

Comment: An annotation can have only one leader line, even in ArcObjects, like Richard said you'd have to place two labels to get two leaders (or draw a line that looks like a leader).

Comment: I think we'll just use another line shapefile for leader lines.

Comment: You might try making a "label points" feature class as well as points of the polylines' mid points and end points ("Feature Vertices to Points" tool). If you can get the "Label Points" and the mid/end points to all have a common attribute (like the line FID) then you can automate connecting the dots ("Points to Line" tool) to draw those leaders as a separate line feature class.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters above have stated, it is not possible for a label to have two leader lines. The only possible workaround is to place two labels, but it is unlikely you could get them to place in the same position, unless you converted to annotation and moved them manually.